# How do I define an inline function in a .cpp file with a signature in a .hpp?

Tags: c++, function, inline, definition, signature

I have the signature of the function in my .hpp file and the definition in my .cpp file.

I get a linker error every time I try this, but it goes away and works just fine as soon as I remove the word 'inline'.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Short answer: you  do not

Comment: The whole point of `inline` is to allow you to place the function definition in the header.  If you are trying to use `inline` to tell the compiler to inline the function, don't worry about it; modern compilers will inline functions that they deem appropriate, regardless of whether or not you give the `inline` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

An inline function must be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used. If you want the function to be inline, you need to define it in the header. If you want to declare it in the header and define it in the `.cpp` file, then don't mark it `inline`.